# Is spring-boot a framework?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm asking this question because I see everywhere people saying spring-boot is a framework. As far as I know, spring-boot is not a framework. This is a tool to make spring application making easier.
Even in spring.io website, this does not say spring-boot is a frawork.

Please, give me your thought about it.
Regards

Comment: Spring is the Framework, Spring boot is just a module of this framework to facilitate the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is the framework.
Spring Boot is a project build to simplify usage of Spring framework, see https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot